# Angular & ng2-smart-table: Multi selectmode checkbox disable

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table, nebular

I'm using ng2-smart-table to display some data, i've set the selectMode to 'multi' in order to have checkboxes on the left side. In the data i have an array of objects which come with a property "set" which is a boolean and can either be true or false, how do i disable the checkbox if the set property is true? Is there a way to do this?

I've already tried making a new renderComponent etc but then i lose the selectAll functionality plus with a renderComponent the selectRow works different.

Here's a link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndmxxg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put a button on the Top, which is initialized to `true`, when you press it, it will disable all the checkboxes;

**NOTE**: I have set this on click of a button so that you see it in action; If you want to do it after getting a boolean variable from the parent or by-default, you'd have to do this inside `ngAfterViewInit()`... since we'd have to wait for the `ng2-smart-table` to be rendered and ready; i left a comment in my stackblitz about it also;

relevant **HTML**:

```
<h3>
    Event Response in Console
</h3>
<button (click)="onClick()"> Disable checkbox </button>
<hr/>
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="data" (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)" (editConfirm)="onSaveConfirm($event)"
 (createConfirm)="onCreateConfirm($event)" (userRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)">
```

relevant **TS**:

```
import { Component, Renderer2, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedMode: boolean = true;
  // This will contain selected rows
  selectedRows: any;

  constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2, private e: ElementRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() { }

  disableCheckboxes() {
    var checkbox = this.e.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    checkbox.forEach((element, index) => {

      /* disable the select all checkbox */
      if (index ==0){this.renderer2.setAttribute(element, "disabled", "true");}

      /* disable the checkbox if set column is false */
      if (index >0 && this.data[index-1].set == false) {
        this.renderer2.setAttribute(element, "disabled", "true");
      }
    });
  }

  settings = {
    selectMode: 'multi',
    delete: {
      confirmDelete: true,

      deleteButtonContent: 'Delete data',
      saveButtonContent: 'save',
      cancelButtonContent: 'cancel'
    },
    add: {
      confirmCreate: true,
    },
    edit: {
      confirmSave: true,
    },
    columns: {
      id: {        title: 'ID',      },
      name: {        title: 'Full Name',      },
      email: {        title: 'Email',      },
      set: {        title: 'Set',      }
    },
  };

  data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Leanne Graham",
      email: "Sincere@april.biz",
      set: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Ervin Howell",
      email: "Shanna@melissa.tv",
      set: false
    },
    // ... list of items
    {
      id: 11,
      name: "Nicholas DuBuque",
      email: "Rey.Padberg@rosamond.biz",
      set: false
    }
  ];

  // UserRowSelected Event handler
  onRowSelect(event) {
    this.selectedRows = event.selected;
  }

  // Get Selected button click handler
  onClick() {
    // It will console all the selected rows
    this.selectedMode = false;
    this.disableCheckboxes();
  }

  onDeleteConfirm(event) {
    console.log("Delete Event In Console")
    console.log(event);
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
      event.confirm.resolve();
    } else {
      event.confirm.reject();
    }
  }

  onCreateConfirm(event) {
    console.log("Create Event In Console")
    console.log(event);
  }

  onSaveConfirm(event) {
    console.log("Edit Event In Console")
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayyeeb)

> **Update** (in light of questioner's comment below):

relevant **CSS**:

```
::ng-deep table tr td:nth-of-type(1),
::ng-deep table tr th:nth-of-type(1)
{ padding:0 !important; display: block;height: 13px; position: relative;}
::ng-deep table tr td:nth-of-type(1) input,
::ng-deep table tr th:nth-of-type(1) input
{ margin:0 !important; position: absolute; top: 15px;}
::ng-deep table tr td:nth-of-type(2),
::ng-deep table tr th:nth-of-type(2)
{ padding: 0 0 0 20px !important;}
```

Comment: They can still be selected/checked even if you disable the checkboxes when you click the box that contains the checkbox.

Comment: When you disable checkboxes, then you click next to checkbox (between checkbox and Edit/Delete) it selects the checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for helping me Akber, i have one question for your edited solution. I have an application that has alot of data with alot of boolean types that are true/false, is your solution dynamic? I would need the check boxes to be disabled depending on those boolean types.

Comment: you can share your appreciation by accepting the answer :-)... for your comment, look at the function `disableCheckboxes()`... here i am getting a reference of all the checkboxes and then disabling them inside the `forEach` loop; you can put a condition there and then decide whether to disable that particular checkbox or not;

Comment: Yes i have tried going through data in forEach and disabling them but it still disabled all of them even.                                                                                             this.data.forEach(x=>{
      if (x.set == false) { this.renderer2.setAttribute(element, "disabled", "true"); }
      })

Comment: does `this.selectedMode` exist for each checkbox? where is this set?

Comment: No, selectedMode does nothing, the data array of objects below has "set" which is a boolean, if "set" value is set to false in the table, then that checkbox needs to be disabled, i edited my comment above.

Comment: check the updated function `disableCheckboxes() {
    var checkbox = this.e.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    checkbox.forEach((element, index) => {

      /* disable the select all checkbox */
      if (index ==0){this.renderer2.setAttribute(element, "disabled", "true");}

      /* disable the checkbox if set column is false */
      if (index >0 && this.data[index-1].set == false) {
        this.renderer2.setAttribute(element, "disabled", "true");
      }
    });
  }`

Comment: It works good now, just need another way to disable selecting checkbox when you click on box next to checkbox. Your answer helped me alot.

Comment: which box next to the checkbox?

Comment: The one you removed with CSS.

Comment: i didn't remove any box... i just removed the padding around the checkbox - this is what was causing the click despite being disabled; you're looking at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayyeeb right?

Comment: Yes, i know you removed the padding but the problem is i have two tables, it removes padding on the other table too. I think there isn't another way unfortunately.

Comment: I created a div which is parent of the table which we do want to modify... made minor changes to the css which is updated on the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayyeeb