# Stop event propagation for mat-select inside mat-checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material, event-handling

I have a `<mat-select>` inside a `<mat-checkbox>`. When there is a change on `<mat-select>`, it also toggles the `<mat-checkbox>` and I do not want this to happen.

I have tried using '$event.stopPropagation()' but it doesn't work. Any ideas how this could be tackled?

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="myCheckboxModel" (change)="onChangeFunction()">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="mySelectModel">
            <mat-option value="1">1</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="2">2</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: maybe you can use CSS to prevent firing of the select checkbox when someone clicks on it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949992/

Comment: What element did you add `$event.stopPropagation()` to? This works for autocomplete and should work for select as well : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50569422/9226213. For checkbox you may need `$event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @g-tranter Adding `$event.stopPropagation()` on `<mat-select>` stops the click event from bubbling to the checkbox above. Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with nested `mat-selection-list` items.

This is working for me.

```
selectionChange(event: MatSelectionListChange)
{
    window['event']?.stopPropagation();
}
```

I'm just finding out today that `window.event` [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event), but in this exact context it's not easy since angular doesn't give us the underlying event.

If you're using SSR make sure not to call this programatically since `window` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked adding (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="myCheckboxModel (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">Checkbox Label</mat-checkbox>
```